# how add style to variables via easy_rich_text widget

Tags: flutter, richtext

how can i add style or conditional style to easy_rich_text widget?
like this ${userData['invoiceAll']}$
and is it possible add condition to that?(if high red color, elseif low green color

```
EasyRichText(
                  "I authorize to change my credit_card below for ${userData['invoiceAll']}\$ on the ${userData['signupday']} Day of each Month ",
                  patternList: [
                    EasyRichTextPattern(
                      targetString: '${userData['invoiceAll']}\$',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    EasyRichTextPattern(
                      targetString: '${userData['signupday']}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
             ),
```

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question or add "solved"; that's what answers are for.

Answer (score 0):

i added hasSpecialCharacters: true and issue fixed